# My Java program compiles without any errors, but will not fully run

Tags: java

Here is the error that I am receiving.

```
thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
```

Here is the code that I am working with. I am able to enter the "last name" but then I get the error message that is displayed above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class lab81
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter last name:");
double lastName;
lastName = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter first name:");
double firstName;
firstName = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter this years units:");
double thisYearsUnits;
thisYearsUnits = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter last years units:");
double lastYearsUnits;
lastYearsUnits = input.nextDouble();
double numberOfUnits = thisYearsUnits;
final double UNITS1 = 1000;
final double UNITS2 = 3000;
final double UNITS3 = 6000;
final double BONUS1 = 25;
final double BONUS2 = 50;
final double BONUS3 = 100;
final double BONUS4 = 200;
if(thisYearsUnits < lastYearsUnits)
{
   double bonusAmount;
   bonusAmount = 0;
   System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
   System.out.println("Bonus is $" + bonusAmount);
}
else if(numberOfUnits <= UNITS1)
{
   double bonusAmount;
   bonusAmount = BONUS1;
   System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
   System.out.println("Bonus is $" + bonusAmount);
}
else if(numberOfUnits <= UNITS2)
{
   double bonusAmount;
   bonusAmount = BONUS2;
   System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
   System.out.println("Bonus is $" + bonusAmount);
}
else if(numberOfUnits <= UNITS3)
{
   double bonusAmount;
   bonusAmount = BONUS3;
   System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
   System.out.println("Bonus is $" + bonusAmount);
}
else if(numberOfUnits > UNITS3)
{
   double bonusAmount;
   bonusAmount = BONUS4;
   System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
   System.out.println("Bonus is $" + bonusAmount);
}
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think `nextDouble` does? Since when are last names numbers?

Comment: When you step through your code in your debugger what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse characters into a double and that's why it's throwing an exception.

Declare your first name & last name as strings and get them from input by using

```
Input.nextLine()
```

Instead of

```
Input.nextDouble()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing text into your firstname and lastname variables? That is obvious data type mismatch. Use Strings, they are what stores text.

```
String firstname;
// Stuff
firstname = input.nextLine();
```

Doubles are for floating point number of a certain length. Also, use int whenever possible.

```
final int UNITS1 = 1000;
final int UNITS2 = 3000;
final int UNITS3 = 6000;
final int BONUS1 = 25;
final int BONUS2 = 50;
final int BONUS3 = 100;
final int BONUS4 = 200;
// Stuff
int bonusAmount;
```

Work on your primitive datatype knowledge. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Cases when these exception are thrown:-

InputMismatchException − if the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range

```
lastname=scaner.nextDouble();
```

At this line you would have been entering string value, however it expecting double.

NoSuchElementException − if the input is exhausted

IllegalStateException − if this scanner is closed